# Solving $(2^x-0.5)\ln(x^2+1)=0$

Tags: calculus

I am trying to solve the following equation:

> $(2^x-0.5)\ln(x^2+1)=0$

First I tried to divide $\displaystyle\frac0{(2^x)-0.5}$ but it didn't work.

I tried to multiply with the $\ln$ but it didn't work either.

Comment: First i tried to divide 0/(2^x)-0.5) but dint work, i tried to multiply with the ln but didnt work..

Answer (score 2):

HINT: $\ln(x^2+1)=0$ or $2^x-1/2=0$

Comment: x=0 or x=-1, so when we have something like ln(x)(2x)=0 we can split them?

And thank you sir !!

Comment: @user239712 Yes. It is a property of real numbers: $ab=0\,\Rightarrow\, (a=0\, \text{ or }\, b=0)$.

Comment: So if i have something like this

> (2^(x))*ln(x)-(1/4)*ln(x)=0

That its valid??
t

Answer (score 0):

I only give you the answers:

$$(2^x-0.5)\ln(x^2+1)=0$$

Real: $x=0$

Complex:

$$x=\frac{i(2\pi n+i\ln(2))}{\ln(2)}$$

(with n is the element of Z -> the set of integers)